# fatal error: benchmark/benchmark.h: No such file or directory

Tags: protocol-buffers, fatal-error, google-benchmark

Does anybody know what the following error message means?

```
fatal error: benchmark/benchmark.h: No such file or directory
#include benchmark/benchmark.h/
```

I should say that I have just installed Google Protobuf.

Comment: Have you install Google Benchmark on your machine? You are supposed to have that installed before compiling your program. Google Benchmark: https://github.com/google/benchmark.

Comment: @Azeem I installed Google benchmark but now I receive another error message:
process.proto:1:10: Unrecognized syntax identifier "proto3".  This parser only recognizes "proto2".

Comment: You have to install the correct version of protobuf also.

Comment: @Azeem I have installed versions 2 and 3 but I receive still this error message. Should I do any other thing? Should I set some environment variables to set which version of protobuf is used?

Comment: You can try by uninstalling the version you don't need. Kindly update your question with some more details about what you are trying to set up. Ideally, with all the steps that you have followed so far. That would help to understand your problem.